# How to prove the uniqueness

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to solve this question from Fulton's algebraic curves:

[image]

I've already easily solved (a) and the existence part of (b). I'm having problems to prove the uniqueness of part (b).

I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, suppose $\lambda_0  + \cdots + \lambda_n t^n + z_n t^{n+1} = \mu_0 + \cdots + \mu_n t^n + w_n t^{n+1}$. What can you say about the difference of the LHS and the RHS?

Comment: @ZhenLin your LHS is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a\in R$ is invertible and $b\in R$ are such that $a+bt=0$, then $a=b=0$: if $b\ne0$, then $a\in\mathfrak m$, a contradiction.

Comment: very clever, thank you very much!